# React-Native Flexbox align items vertical

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Im new to React-Native and want to display items within a container vertically. But for some reasons I cannot see the TextInput on Android.
Firstly I didnt see it on iOS, but by adding `position: "absolute"` to the TextInput I was able to see it on iOS, android is still missing. I dont know why. (I'm using wix/react-native-ui-lib)

[image: Problem]

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Text, Button, Image } from "react-native-ui-lib";

class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View useSafeArea={true} style={style.Main}>
        <View style={style.phoneBox}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
            source={require("../../assets/icons/country_austria.png")}
          />
          <Text text50>+43</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ position: "absolute" }}
            text50
            placeholder="Handynummer eingeben"
            hideUnderline={true}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const style = {
  Main: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  phoneBox: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "stretch"
  }
};

export default MainScreen;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: Looks a problem with the library that you are using setting flex: 0 and adding a width fixes for both, android and ios you can check the demo in both apetizers

```
<TextInput
   style={{width: 250, flex: 0}}
   text50
   placeholder="Handynummer eingeben"
   hideUnderline={true}
/>
```

[image][image]
Here a [demo](https://snack.expo.io/S1jcTbjOM)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I did not see you are using wix/react-native-ui-lib

Comment: Thank you very much for participating in my problem and for your solution. It works!